# Flutter Web : How to Link to a Specific Line or Paragraph on a Web Page

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How do I get the ability to reference to a particular part of the page (a paragraph or a tab) in Flutter web. In traditional web url, this is made possible by anchoring the `div` to be references with a `#`. For e.g. in the link `https://cloud.google.com/customers/featured/paypal#take-the-next-step`, the link takes as directly to the `div` that is tagged as *take-the-next-step*

Is there a way to do this in Flutter Web yet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current URL and parse it for the parameter at the end of the URL. You can get the current URL with this code:

```
import 'dart:html';

var url = window.location.href;
```

Using the parameter that you have parsed, you can change the position on the page with your `ScrollController`(or whatever method you're using to change page position) to the desired place on screen.

Comment: How would the url be updated when a different reference is clicked ?

Comment: You can set the current URL with `window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";`. Why do you need the url to be updated on click? This should be able to be handled within flutter without any help from the URL.